# Construction of $A$-mixtilinear incircle .

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

The $A-$mixtilinear incircle of a triangle $ABC$ is the circle internally tangent to $(ABC)$, as
well as to sides $AB$ and $AC$.

This is from Euclidean Geometry in mathematical Olympiad.
[image: t]
I wonder, how can we do this construction.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/MixtilinearConstruction.shtml#Yiu1

Comment: oh..I see thanks !

Comment: you are welcome :)